# Storing binary data in static array

Tags: c, buffer

I'm writing an application which reads data from a UART interface. The data is sent in packets. Each packet has a channel associated with it. My application multiplexes received packets into virtual channels (threads) so that every channel can work independently of one another. When I receive a packet I have to do something depending on it's contents and produce a response. The response is sent back using the same UART interface.

The data sent is mostly binary. When I'm reading from the UART interface, I know the size of the packet beforehand, so I can preallocate memory with no problem.

The problem for me is producing a response. I know the maximum size of a packet, so I can create a static buffer when I'm constructing a response. If I we're to work with ASCII characters, instead of binary data, I could rely on NULL terminator to determine how long the data stored in the buffer is. However, I'm working with binary data, so using a NULL byte does not work. Instead, I have to keep a variable storing how many bytes of the buffer is used up already. I was thinking of using a custom data type for storing binary data:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char buff[2048];
    size_t buff_used;
} binary_data_t;
```

What would be a standart way of handling this?

Comment: There's no "standard" way, but what you have started on not uncommon. Then add a set of functions to append different kinds of data to the buffer.

Comment: Is there a library for this kind of problem? I feel like I'm reinventing a wheel.

Comment: @PoVa Of course, but recommending libraries is off-topic for this site. Re-inventing wheels is on-topic (modulo dupes), however. :)

Comment: Your approach is fine.  A library is overkill - you have to track how much data you have anyway - if you can't do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the number of bytes you need to hold a packet, just use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t bytes;
    unsigned char data[];
} binary_data_t;
```

(Note that [identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_12), and you really shouldn't be using them.)

Allocation and reading data (assumes you `read()` from a file descriptor):

```
binary_data_t *p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) + numDataBytes );
p->bytes = numDataBytes;
ssize_t bytes_read = read( uartFD, p->data, numDataBytes );
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using something similar. One question, what's the point of using flexible array members? Isn't it the same (under the hood) as declaring a pointer and allocating space for it?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it could be to store a pointer to where in your array next byte should be placed.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char buff[2048];
    char*    pData;
} binary_data_t;

// at init
binary_data_t rspMsg;
rspMsg.pData = &rspMsg.buff[0];

// at entering data
*(rspMsg.pData) = data;
rspMsg.pData++;

// at sending data you know the length via
length = rspMsg.pData - &rspMsg.buff[0];
```

This is one way of solving this. 
Can be done in many ways.

Comment: Your code is not valid, you treat the structure's fields like local variables which is very confusing. Consider that the OP might not be very experienced in writing C. Post real code when possible.

Comment: Ok I will change it